# Reuse element defined further up in App.xaml

Tags: wpf

I declare several converters in my App.xaml as follows but I am repeating myself which I really would like to avoid:

```
<c:ConverterChain x:Key="IsNotNull">
  <c:IsNullConverter />
  <c:InvertBoolConverter />
</c:ConverterChain>

<c:ConverterChain x:Key="HideWhenNull">
  <c:IsNullConverter />
  <c:InvertBoolConverter />
  <c:BoolToFromVisibilityConverter FalseEquivalent="Hidden" />
</c:ConverterChain>

<c:ConverterChain x:Key="CollapseWhenNull">
  <c:IsNullConverter />
  <c:InvertBoolConverter />
  <c:BoolToFromVisibilityConverter FalseEquivalent="Collapsed" />
</c:ConverterChain>
```

As you can see the `IsNotNull` could be reused in the two following converter chains, but is it possible to declare that somehow? I'm thinking of something like:

```
<c:ConverterChain x:Key="HideWhenNull">
  <Reference Name="IsNotNull" />
  <c:BoolToFromVisibilityConverter FalseEquivalent="Hidden" />
</c:ConverterChain>
```

Is there some WPF concept out there to cover this use case?

Comment: Your edit changes the question entirely, from "can I solve a particular problem" to "what's wrong with my code that's solving this problem." That's not great for the format of StackOverflow; really there should be two questions, and your edit (once it's working!) should probably be posted as an answer to the first question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I deleted the edit section and will post it as an separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by Khyads answer I opted for StaticResource instead of DynamicResource because there is no need for the extra overhead Dynamic implies and it works just fine with a static resource:

```
<c:ConverterChain x:Key="HideWhenNull">
  <StaticResource ResourceKey="IsNotNull" />
  <c:BoolToFromVisibilityConverter FalseEquivalent="Hidden" />
</c:ConverterChain>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<c:ConverterChain x:Key="HideWhenNull">
  <DynamicResource  ResourceKey="IsNotNull"/>
  <c:BoolToFromVisibilityConverter FalseEquivalent="Hidden" />
</c:ConverterChain>
```

As long as the ConverterChain class supports nesting.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. StaticResource works fine in my case.