# Dependency property not set on resource declared in App.xaml

Tags: wpf

This is a follow-up question for ["Reuse element defined further up in App.xaml"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371552/reuse-element-defined-further-up-in-app-xaml/). I tried to solve it by implementing a ConverterReference-Converter:

```
public class ConverterReference : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ConverterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Converter", typeof (ConverterBase), typeof(ConverterReference));

  public ConverterBase Converter 
  { 
    get { return (ConverterBase)GetValue(ConverterProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ConverterProperty, value); }
  }

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return this.Converter.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return this.Converter.ConvertBack(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
  }
}
```

In my App.xaml I declare it as follows:

```
<c:ConverterChain x:Key="IsNotNull">
  <c:IsNullConverter />
  <c:InvertBoolConverter />
</c:ConverterChain>

<c:ConverterChain x:Key="HideWhenNull">
  <!-- see here -->
  <c:ConverterReference Converter="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource IsNotNull}}" />
  <c:BoolToFromVisibilityConverter FalseEquivalent="Hidden" />
</c:ConverterChain>
```

However when I use this converter in a binding

```
<Label Content="Hello world!" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource HideWhenNull}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

the compiler tells me that there is a null-reference and by debugging I found out that the Dependency Property of the ConverterReference instance declared in App.xaml does not get set, therefore when the binding tries to get the converter it gets null back for ConverterReference.Converter. What have I forgotten?

Comment: What if you don't use a binding, and just write `<c:ConverterReference Converter="{StaticResource IsNotNull}"/>`?

Comment: Then I could directly go with `<StaticResource ResourceKey="IsNotNull" />`. Or is there some benefit your suggestion has? In general I wanted to know why the dependecy property is not working in order to gain some deeper understanding.

Comment: Just think of resources as plain objects. You don't need the binding here, and you don't need to have a dependency property here.